# Sound muted when system locked

Tags: sound, greeter

The sound is automatically muted when the system is locked. How can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is undesirable but unavoidable. It is a result of X, where a new tty is used when locked. Wayland will supposedly fix it.

Comment: When it will be fixed ? I'm thinking to change to another distro

Comment: I couldn't give an estimate other than saying "not soon". Unfortunately, this is likely something that will affect many distributions, or we would be copying what they do to solve it.

Comment: This is also a security issue, if I'm not mistaken. If your music is playing while your screen is locked, it might present a vulnerability in the system.

Comment: It's certainly avoidable, and it has nothing to do with X since X doesn't do sound. I think it's a policykit configuration issue, but being able to write the desired policy might take a bit of programming.

Comment: @Gilles I was informed by elementary developers that Pantheon Greeter kills X when locking, effectively resetting the tty, which results in everything stopping. If this is incorrect, then it is likely this misunderstanding that has lead to this remaining broken. Do let me know if you can suggest a fix or patch.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a terminal and type (be aware of update user with your username before executing the command):

```
sudo adduser user audio
```

Reboot your system and done!